# How to save a date in Firebase Database? [Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on this App which should be able to notice if some date is stored in the database and if not store one itself.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var newPostDate = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

var post_date:String = newPostDate = "" ? ref.child("\(newPostDate)/date").setValue("\(day).\(month).\(year)") : newPostDate?["date"] as? String
```

It gives me this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'NSDictionary?'

Comment: You cannot save a new record without knowing field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check newPostDate with nil as its dictionary not string and also you missed the "==". 
so, it should be like this :

```
var post_date:String = newPostDate == nil ? ref.child("\(newPostDate)/date").setValue("\(day).\(month).\(year)") : newPostDate?["date"] as? String
```

Comment: after updating. I get this error 'Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to specified type 'String''